# display/hide asterisk based on text input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP form and I'm trying to display asterisks after the input boxes `txt1`, `txt1`, and `txt3` if they are empty. It shows the asterisks if empty after hitting the submit button but I want to be able to remove the asterisk after hitting the button if the field has already been filled. The code below doesn't seem to do that last bit.

```
//variable declaration
var a = $("#txt1").val(),
        b = $('#txt2').val(),
        c = $("#txt3").val();
function asterisks() {
    if (a == ""){
        document.getElementById("err_txt1").innerHTML = "*";
    }
    else if (a != ""){
        document.getElementById("err_txt1").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (b == ""){
        document.getElementById("err_txt2").innerHTML = "*";
    }
    else if (b != ""){
        document.getElementById("err_txt2").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (c == ""){
        document.getElementById("err_txt3").innerHTML = "*";
    }
    else if (c != ""){
        document.getElementById("err_txt3").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Is there a better approach to this? Is it possible to remove the asterisk as soon as the fields get filled without having to press the button? If yes, how?

**Sample field HTML**

```
<style>
    .err {
        color: #FF0000;
    }
</style>

<td><h3>Subject</h3></td>
<td><b id="err_txt1" class="err"></b><input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" placeholder="Subject" >
</td>
```

**Submit form**

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    asterisks();
}
```

Comment: when do you call the function `asterisks()`?

Comment: Share relevant html

Comment: You have to add onkeydown event handler to your elements

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it's in the submit button <input type='submit' onclick='asterisks()' id="btnsub" name="btnsub" value="Submit">

Comment: Try changing the `else if` to `else` — if `c == ""` is false, `c != ""` must be true.

Comment: @Mel Is any of the answers working for you? You dont give much response to anyone

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen sorry i was trying out the codes

Comment: @user6016913 i just added some. is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as simple as:

```
function asterisks() {
  $("input[id^=txt]").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("txt", "");
    $("#err_txt" + id).text(($(this).val() ? "*" : ""))
  });
};
```

Let's break down `input[id^=txt]`:

`input` = Is quite clear, the selector for the input element.
`id^=txt` This means we will select all elements with an `id` that starts with (`^=`) `txt`

**Demo**

```js
function asterisks() {
  $("input[id^=txt]").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("txt", "");
    $("#err_txt" + id).text(($(this).val() ? "*" : ""))
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1" value="*" /><label id="err_txt1"></label>
<input id="txt2" value="" /><label id="err_txt2"></label>
<input id="txt3" value="*" /><label id="err_txt3"></label>






<input type='submit' onclick='asterisks()' id="btnsub" name="btnsub" value="Submit">
```

**Demo 2**

```js
$("#form1").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  asterisks();
})

function asterisks() {
  $("input[id^=txt]").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("txt", "");
    $("#err_txt" + id).html(($(this).val().length == 0 ? "*" : ""))
  });
};
```

```css
.err {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3>Subject</h3>
      </td>
      <td><b id="err_txt1" class="err"></b><input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" placeholder="Subject">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3>Subject</h3>
      </td>
      <td><b id="err_txt2" class="err"></b><input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt1" placeholder="Subject">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3>Subject</h3>
      </td>
      <td><b id="err_txt3" class="err"></b><input type="text" id="txt3" name="txt1" placeholder="Subject">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type='submit' id="btnsub" name="btnsub" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @Mel `input[id^=text]` is a selector that matches all inputs that have an `id` that start with `txt`

Comment: @mel check the update and see if it makes sense for you

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you for explaining! this seems to make a lot of sense but I'm not sure why it isn't working for me. I'll try it again

Comment: @Mel If you post your html code in your answer, then i can tell you why it dont work

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen this is the span that holds the * `<b id="err_txt1" class="err"></b>` (class err just turns it red). It doesn't work as is but if I added an asterisk within the tags (i.e., `<b>*</b>)` it works albeit the inverse of what I wanted to happen. the asterisk appears when something is entered in the field and disappears when the field is empty

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen check edit. something like that?

Comment: @Mel Try look at demo 2

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0):

You have your code ready but with no execution. Since you have asked for a better way to do this, consider having this code:

(I saw you used jQuery so why not use it all the way)

```js
$('input.text').blur(function() {
 if ($(this).val() == '') {
   $('.err_text').empty().append('*');
  } else {
   $('.err_text').empty();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text">
<input type="text" class="text">
<input type="text" class="text">
<span class="err_text"></span>
```

Comment: 'You can see the op have multiple inputs and multiple labels with corresponding ids

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using jquery you can use onkeyup event to check whether there is any value or not. for example

```
$('#txt1').on('keyup', function(){

       if(this.val().length)
       {
            $('#err_txt1').val('');
       }
       else
       {
            $('#err_txt1').val('*');
       }
});
```

and Let your form id is form1 then write that checking on submit of your form.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event){

     if(!$("#txt1").val().length)
     {
         $('#err_txt1').val('*');
         return false;
     }

     if(!$("#txt2").val().length)
     {
         $('#err_txt2').val('*');
         return false;
     }

     if(!$("#txt3").val().length)
     {
         $('#err_txt3').val('*');
         return false;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways in which you can handle this.

As you probably want instant feedback i would recommend using the on input event as it will update your asterisk upon typing or deleting.

One would be to attach an event to the input via [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput):

```js
function checkEmpty(sender) {
  if ($(sender).val() == "") {
    $(sender).prev().html("*");
  } else {
    $(sender).prev().html("");
  }
}
```

```css
.err {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td>
  <h3>Subject 1</h3>
</td>
<td>
  <b id="err_txt1" class="err">*</b>
  <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" placeholder="Subject 1" oninput="checkEmpty(this);">
</td>
<td>
  <h3>Subject 2</h3>
</td>
<td>
  <b id="err_txt2" class="err">*</b>
  <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" placeholder="Subject 2" oninput="checkEmpty(this);">
</td>
<td>
  <h3>Subject 3</h3>
</td>
<td>
  <b id="err_txt3" class="err">*</b>
  <input type="text" id="txt3" name="txt3" placeholder="Subject 3" oninput="checkEmpty(this);">
</td>
```

Another would be to attach the event using jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").on("input", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).prev().html("*");
    } else {
      $(this).prev().html("");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.err {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td>
  <h3>Subject 1</h3>
</td>
<td>
  <b id="err_txt1" class="err">*</b>
  <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" placeholder="Subject 1">
</td>
<td>
  <h3>Subject 2</h3>
</td>
<td>
  <b id="err_txt2" class="err">*</b>
  <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" placeholder="Subject 2">
</td>
<td>
  <h3>Subject 3</h3>
</td>
<td>
  <b id="err_txt3" class="err">*</b>
  <input type="text" id="txt3" name="txt3" placeholder="Subject 3">
</td>
```

Comment: You should Never have multiple elements with the same ID

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen You are right that was a typo I have fixed the issue. I was trying to have some HTML structure that reflected the OP's question but failed to update all the ID's.

Comment: @fjoe hi this makes a lot of sense to me but i cant seem to make it work at all :(

Comment: @Mel if you give me your actual HTML I can change the JavaScript to reflect your structure.

Comment: @Mel I have modified my answer to better reflect the HTML structure you supplied.

Comment: @fjoe this is exactly what i needed but alas, i can't seem to make it work. thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any input in the form with that html structure

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#myForm input').on('input', function (e) {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        var $asterisk = $(this).parent().find('.asterisk');
          inputValue ? $asterisk.addClass('hide') :  $asterisk.removeClass('hide');
      });
    });
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myForm'>
      <div>
          <span class='asterisk hide'>*</span>
          <label> Name</label>
          <input type='text' name='name' value='' />
      </div>
    </form>
```